# Magento website transfer from server to local

Tags: magento-1.9

I am transferring my website from a server to local. I did all database setting in local.xml file and change the url in core_config_data table.

But it showing me some error.

```
Decoding failed: Syntax error

Trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Helper\Data.php(659): Zend_Json::decode('', 1)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\code\community\MT\RevSlider\Model\Slider.php(246): Mage_Core_Helper_Data->jsonDecode(NULL)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(226): MT_RevSlider_Model_Slider->_afterLoad()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\code\community\MT\RevSlider\Block\Slider\Preview.php(34): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load('3')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): MT_RevSlider_Block_Slider_Preview->_toHtml()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Text\List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('preface', true)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\design\frontend\mtcolias\lalcostore\template\page\1column.phtml(57): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('preface')
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend\\mtcoli...')
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(SkyMagento_Redirect_IndexController), 'lalco-home-page')
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\controllers\IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(SkyMagento_Redirect_IndexController), 'lalco-home-page')
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#24 C:\xampp\htdocs\lalco\index.php(92): Mage::run('', 'store')
#25 {main}
```

I am new on the magento. It takes my lots of time .please help me to find the solution

Thanks in Advance

Comment: is any one available ????

Comment: the error comes from Mage_Core_Helper_Data->jsonDecode(NULL)...
you should debug your code by MT_RevSlider_Model_Slider->_afterLoad()

Comment: @roman204 . i don't know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Disable 'MT_RevSlider' module and run setup upgrade and deployment steps again.
Seems there is some issue in this module. Later you can debug that.

Answer (score 0):

This links can help you.

This has been resolved in Inchoo's Magento PHP 7 compatibility module:

https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7